# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Product" while trying to send routes in TypeScript

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, parsing, routes

I am currently a beginner working on my very first web application and I am trying to use CRUD methods for my product component. I am able to do perform all four functionalities in NodeJs which I have used in backend for creating Restful API. But I am not being able to pass the route in my TypeScript file. I have tried it bu gathering many references but I am getting the error `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Product"`.

Here is the code I have used in my TypeScript file for `my-products.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RestApiService } from '../rest-api.service';
import { DataService } from '../data.service' ;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-products',
  templateUrl: './my-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-products.component.scss']
})
export class MyProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  productId: any;
  products: any;
  btnDisabled = false;
  constructor(private data: DataService, private rest: RestApiService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
  
   
   async remove() {
   const data = await this.rest.delete(
      `http://localhost:397/api/seller/products/${this.productId}`
    );
    data['success']
      ? (this.products = data['products'])
      : this.data.error(data['message']);
  } catch (error) {
    this.data.error(error['message']);
  }

  async update() {
    this.btnDisabled = true;
    try {
      // if (this.validate(this.products)) {
        const form = new FormData();
        for (const key in this.products) {
          if (this.products.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key === 'images') {
              form.append(
                'images',
                this.products.images,
                this.products.images.name
            );
            } else {
            form.append(key, this.products[key]);
            }
          }
        }
        const data = await this.rest.put(
        'http://localhost:397/api/seller/products/${this.productId}',
        form
        );
        data['success']
          ? this.data.success(data['message'])
          : this.data.error(data['message']);
      // }
    } catch (error) {
      this.data.error(error['message']);
    }
    this.btnDisabled =false;
  }

}
```

I am posting with hope of getting the solution here. Thank you guys for being so awesome.

Comment: Which line is the error ?

Comment: the error was in the route so I was unable to parse the id value for remove and delete function. But it has been solved. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It was minor error. I finally solved the issue.If anyone is having difficulty in parsing the values in typescript, Here is what I did to pass the value of id for remove function:

```
 async remove(id: any) {
 const data = await this.rest.delete(
      `http://localhost:397/api/seller/products/${id}`
      
    );
    if (data['success']){
     this.data.success(data['message'])
    }
    else {
      this.data.error(data['message'])
    }
    } catch (error) {
    this.data.error(error['message']);
```

The by this method it will automatically get the ObjectId value and follows the given route. I have done same for the update as well.